# Reverse Polish Notation for array elements. (example: array_name[i,j])

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm, stack, rpn

I need to covert expressions like array_name[i, i*k, i-k] into Reverse Polish Notation. 
What I'm basically doing is trying to translate the expression like this: 
`if(array_name[i, j+k]>=a+b) array_name[i, j*k] = a+2; else x = a / b;` 
into the RPN using regular expressions.
I already have quite an ugly huge regular expression, which matches: `if, else, + - * / = == ( ) <= >= < > !=` and all the words that match this pattern: `[a-zA-z][a-zA-z0-9_]*`. And also I have the code that translates infix arithmetical expressions into RPN. Here it is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the collection of all the lexemes of the expression 
/// using Regex.
/// The Regex created works fine with 'if else' constructions and is good 
///with 
///any variable name possible in C#, with arithmetical expressions, 
///like +, -, /, and all the boolean operators.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">String expression in infix notation.</param>
/// <returns>Collection of all the lexemes of the expression</returns>
private static MatchCollection GetMatchCollection(string input)
{
    var rx =
        new Regex(
            @"/\bif\b|\belse\b|\(|\)|\+|\-|\*|\<=|\>=|\\|\>|\<|(?<![!=])[!=]=(?!=)|([a-zA-Z][a-zA-z0-9_]*)|(\d+\.?\d*)|(?<!=)=(?!=)|\/|/^/g");
    return rx.Matches(input);
}


/// <summary>
/// Translates the infix expression into RPN
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">String expression in infix notation.</param>
/// <returns>RPN expression</returns>
public static string Translate(string input)
{
    var mc = GetMatchCollection(input);

    var id = new Regex(@"[a-zA-z][a-zA-z0-9_]*"); // regex for identifiers
    var num = new Regex(@"\d+\.?\d*"); // regex for decimals
    var skobki = new Regex(@"\(|\)"); // regex for braces
    object[] operators =
    {
        "(", ")", "else", "*", "/", "+", "-", "=", "<", ">", "<=", ">=", "==", "!=", "&&",
        "||", "if"
    }; // operators by priority

    var opers = new Regex(@"\(|\)|\+|\-|\*|\/|<=?|>=?|!=|=|&&|\|\|\bif\b|\belse\b"); // regex for operators

    var stOper = new Stack();
    var expr = new ArrayList();
    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        var m1 = id.Match(m.Value);
        if (m1.Success) { expr.Add(m1.Value); continue; }
        m1 = num.Match(m.Value);
        if (m1.Success) { expr.Add(m1.Value); continue; }
        m1 = skobki.Match(m.Value);
        if (m1.Success)
        {
            if (m1.Value == "(") { stOper.Push(m1.Value); continue; }
            var op = stOper.Pop().ToString();
            while (op != "(")
            {
                expr.Add(op);
                op = stOper.Pop().ToString();
            }
            continue;
        }
        m1 = opers.Match(m.Value);
        if (m1.Success)
        {
            try
            {
                while (Array.IndexOf(operators, m1.Value) > Array.IndexOf(operators, stOper.Peek()))
                {
                    if (stOper.Peek().ToString() == "(") break;
                    expr.Add(stOper.Pop().ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // stack is empty
            }
            stOper.Push(m1.Value);
        }
    }
    while (stOper.Count != 0)
    {
        expr.Add(stOper.Pop().ToString());
    }


    // Make the RPN expression string 
    // from the ArrayList expr.
    var res = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var s in expr)
        res.Append(s).Append(' ');
    return res.ToString();
}
```

How can I modify the code to make the method `public static string Translate(string input)` translate simple expressions like array_name[i,k*i-1] into the RPN expression?

Note, that the `public static string Translate(string input)` method works fine only with simple arithmetical expressions, but not with the one I provided above (the if-else statement).

Comment: The standard way is to use the shunting yard algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: Well, the reason why I'm asking is because all the RPN questions concern RPN calculators and nothing else. I've already read about the shunting yard algorithm and didn't really get it. Probably I have to try again.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the Stroustrup desk calculator. It is in C++ but you will get the princimple. First the input stream is tokenized then evaluated. http://www.stroustrup.com/dc.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Here is the algorithm.

```
class InfixToPostfixConverter
    {
        private readonly Stack<string> _stack;
        private readonly string[] _input;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _priorities;
        private readonly List<string> _poliz;

        public InfixToPostfixConverter(string input)
        {
            _input = input.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            _stack = new Stack<string>();
            _poliz = new List<string>();

            _priorities = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
                {"(", 0},
                {")", 0},
                {"[", 0},
                {"if", 0},
                {"flag", 0},
                {">", 1},
                {"<", 1},
                {"<=", 1},
                {">=", 1},
                {"=", 1},
                {"==", 1},
                {"!=", 1},
                {"+", 2},
                {"-", 2},
                {"*", 3},
                {"/", 3},
                {"^", 4},
                {"@", 5}
            };
        }

        public string Translate()
        {
            return ConvertInfixToPostfix();
        }

        private string ConvertInfixToPostfix()
        {
            int countAts = 0;

            bool reachedElse = false;

            foreach (var lexeme in _input)
            {

                if (lexeme.Equals("if"))
                {
                    _stack.Push(lexeme);
                    _stack.Push("flag");

                }

                else if (lexeme.Equals("else"))
                {
                    _poliz.Add("null");
                    _poliz.Add("1B");
                    reachedElse = true;
                    _poliz[_poliz.FindIndex(x => x.Equals("null"))] = _poliz.Count.ToString();

                }

                else if (Regex.IsMatch(lexeme, @"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-z0-9_]*|\d+\.?\d*")
                         && !lexeme.Equals("if") && !lexeme.Equals("else"))
                {
                    _poliz.Add(lexeme);

                }

                else if (lexeme.Equals(";"))
                {
                    if (!reachedElse)
                    {
                        while (_stack.Count != 0 && !_stack.Peek().Equals("if"))
                        {
                            _poliz.Add(_stack.Pop());
                        }


                        if (_stack.Count != 0)
                        {
                            _stack.Pop();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (_stack.Count != 0)
                        {
                            _poliz.Add(_stack.Pop());
                        }
                        _poliz[_poliz.FindIndex(x => x.Equals("null"))] = _poliz.Count.ToString();
                    }
                }

                else if (lexeme.Equals(","))
                {
                    countAts++;
                    while (_stack.Count != 0 && !_stack.Peek().Equals("["))
                    {
                        _poliz.Add(_stack.Pop());
                    }
                }

                else if (lexeme.Equals(")") || lexeme.Equals("]"))
                {
                    var brace = lexeme.Equals(")") ? "(" : "[";

                    while (_stack.Count != 0 && !_stack.Peek().Equals(brace))
                    {
                        _poliz.Add(_stack.Pop());
                    }
                    _stack.Pop();

                    if (_stack.Peek().Equals("flag"))
                    {
                        _stack.Pop();
                        _poliz.Add((_poliz.Count + 3).ToString());
                        _poliz.Add("null");
                        _poliz.Add("3Y");
                    }

                    if (lexeme.Equals("]"))
                    {
                        countAts++;
                        _poliz.Add(countAts.ToString());
                        _poliz.Add(_stack.Pop());
                        countAts = 0;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    if (_stack.Count != 0 && !lexeme.Equals("(") && !lexeme.Equals("["))
                    {
                        for (;
                            _stack.Count != 0 &&
                            _priorities[lexeme] <= _priorities[_stack.Peek()];
                            _poliz.Add(_stack.Pop())) {}
                    }

                    if (lexeme.Equals("["))
                    {
                        countAts++;
                        _stack.Push("@");
                    }
                    _stack.Push(lexeme);
                }

            }


            return _poliz.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, x) => current + (x + " "));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are not the way to go. [Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) it, probably leveraging some [parser generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler), into an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and the output it into RPN, which is [trivial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piece_of_cake).